# What's the difference between apache-thrift and the thrift-server used in Cassandra?

Tags: php, cassandra, xampp, thrift

I want to connect php from XAMPP to Cassandra.

I have installed cassandra and xampp.

After searching over the internet, I got to know that thrift interface and any one php cassandra client is required for the connection.

For php cassandra client I am using `phpcassa`.

There is `thrift-server.exe` in the lib folder of cassandra. Is it working as a thrift interface What is the purpose of it?

Thanks

Comment: I just double-checked against [2.1.5](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/cassandra/2.1.5/apache-cassandra-2.1.5-bin.tar.gz), but there's only a `thrift-server-0.3.7.jar`, not an `exe`. Would be strange anyway, since `exe` is a typical Windows thing, while Cassandra is Java-based and runs on many platforms, not just Windows. Next, the question title is misleading: You ask about the purpose of a particular `exe` file but the title says something completely different.

Comment: its my mistake.`thrift-server` is a jar file.I wanted to know the difference between `apache-thrift` and the `thrift-server` used in cassandra. I am a newbie to stackoverflow.may be the title is wrong but i want to learn cassandra from the core.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the DataStax PHP driver [1](http://github.com/datastax/php-driver) and use CQL instead of Thrift.